# When I pass a null, which overloaded function will java run

Tags: java, methods, reference, null, overloading

So i can pass nulls into functions in java. I can also overload functions in java. But consider the following

```
public static void main(String ... args){
    doStuff(null);
}

public static void doStuff(String s){
      solveWorldHunger();
}

public static void doStuff(Integer i){
      nukeCanada();
}

public static void nukeCanada(){
 System.out.println("NO!");
}

public static void solveWorldHunger(){
  System.out.println("YAY!");
}
```

The previous program will always print out YAY no matter what the order of the sorce code...

Can anyone shed some light onto why the jvm consitently decides to run the `solveWorldHunger` function over the `nukeCanada` function`?

Comment: Well, to begin with an `int` cannot be null... An example with `Integer` might be more interesting.

Comment: Because Java is a benevolent programming language.

Comment: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12.2.5

Comment: If you overload your method with different complex types, you have to cast the null to one of these types.

Comment: Now your edited code won't compile. Ambiguity in method invocation.

Comment: @mbelow Only if they are incommensurable.

Comment: @EJP No, this is valid for any complex type.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's quite clear to the compiler that you can't store `null` in a `primitive int`. So, it decides to go with the method which has `String` as argument.

However, when you change your 2nd method to take `Integer` as argument, then you will get compiler error. Because both of them are eligible to be invoked with `null` argument. So, there will be ambiguity.

So, try changing your 2nd method: -

```
public static void doStuff(String s){
      solveWorldHunger();
}

public static void doStuff(Integer i){  // Integer instead of `int`
      nukeCanada();
}
```

And invoke it on `null`. You will see the compiler error.

So, in that case, you can invoke the appropriate method using typecasting like this: -

```
doStuff((Integer)null);  // Calls Integer version
doStuff((String)null);   // Calls String version
```

---

Also, note that, if you have your `2nd method` take a parameter that is a `super type` of `String`, like `Object`, then there would be no ambiguity, because compiler will now choose the most specific one, i.e., `String` argument.

So, ambiguity only occurs, when you have two methods with types that are not in the same inheritance hierarchy.

Answer (score 1):

Only your doStuff(String) method can take a NULL argument... the primitive int can never be null.  If you had a second method overload that passed an object, you would no longer be able to pass null as a parameter for that method.

Comment: The part about the second overload is not correct. If he had another overload that took Object for example, the overload taking String would be chosen as being most specific. If he only had overloads of incommensurable types, such as String and Integer, he would get a compilation error.

Comment: Good catch - I didn't mean object as in Object, and I also didn't know that.  Thanks!